# facebook android sdk v3.23 doesn't return to activity after ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am sharing the app on facebook. Once i do that, the facebook post doesn't take me back to my activity. Instead displays a toast saying "your post is shared" and loops back to the share page. 
Is there anything i am doing wrong?

```
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setLink(SharedVariables.url)
                .setName("Name")
                .setCaption("Caption")
                .setDescription("Description")
                .build();
        shareDialog.present();
SharedVariables.uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your activity marked `android:noHistory="true"` in your AndroidManifest.xml, it will not return. Please check for this.

There is also a duplicate of `present()` call in the code:

```
shareDialog.present();
SharedVariables.uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Try removing the first one - it should not be needed.

Comment: No :( Checked that. I am nowhere setting that.